# get_selectedItem().get_value() Not Working for RadComboBox

Tags: telerik

I use following code to try to get current selected value of a Telerik RadComboBox:

```
 var combobox = $find("<%= cboBoxA.ClientID %>");
        var txt = combobox.get_selectedItem().get_value();
```

But I get following JavaScript error:

**Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_value'**

What is the problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked for me:

```
var combobox = $find("<%= cboBoxA.ClientID %>");
    var txt = combobox.get_text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var combo = $find('<%=cboBoxA.ClientID %>');
alert(combo.get_selectedItem().get_value());
```

Refer to these links
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/overview
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/objects/radcombobox-object
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/objects/radcomboboxitemcollection-object